# Java Inheritance and Variables

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I know this is very basic but I am having trouble putting the pieces together in an unfamiliar language. I'm mapping UML into Java code and inheritance is throwing me. I have an ERD like this:

```
Animal
----------------------------
-color: int
-weight: int
----------------------------
+ getColor() : int
+ getWeight(): int
----------------------------
         ^(Inheritance Triangle)
         |
         |
----------------------------
Dog
----------------------------
-breed: string
----------------------------
+ getBreed()
----------------------------
```

So of course a dog IS-A animal, and I can call getColor from a dog class, etc. My problem is about the variables, in particular contructors.  When I implement this, I have

```
public class Animal 
{
    private int color;
    private int weight;

    public Animal(int c, int w)
    {
        color = c;
        weight = w;
    }
   ...
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
    private string breed;

    public Dog()
    {
        breed = "Shelty";
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the proper way to use color and weight in the dog class? Looking at the UML, I know I could put color and weight in the dog entity, but I understand that's optional. Would I just also have a private color and weight attribute in the dog class? Would I call the Animal constructor (which throws errors) What is the proper form here?

Comment: you want to set the value of attributes of class Animal from Dog class or want to access it in Dog class ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Dog` class's responsibility should be to initialize whatever *new* functionality it is adding, and let the super class initialize all properties that the `Dog` class has inherited.

You could do something like this:

```
public class Dog extends Animal
{
    private String breed;

    public Dog(int color, int weight, String breed)
    {
        super(color,weight); //let superclass initialize these.
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the keyword super.

```
public Dog(int c, int w){
    super(c,w);
    breed = "Shelty";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional to answer of manish,
You can also write a NoArg constructor to provide default initialization values.

```
public class Dog extends Animal
{
    private String breed;

    public Dog(int color, int weight, String breed)
    {
        super(color,weight); //let superclass initialize these.
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    // Default initialization if required
    public Dog() {
        this ( 0, 0, "Shelty")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Dog extends Animal
{
    private String breed;

    //Declaring default constructor is a good practice

    public Dog() 
    {
      //Some default values
       int color=3,weight =8;
       super(color,weight);
       this.breed = "pug";
    }

    public Dog(int color, int weight, String breed)
    {
       super(color,weight); 
       this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

Comment: May we know the reason for providing same ans again ?

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar It might be due to You're editing your answer in the same time where i post my answer.